# How to download _full_ RefSeq record using Efetch?

Tags: biopython, ncbi, genbank

I have a problem downloading a full record from Nucleotide db. 
I use:

```
from Bio import Entrez
from Bio import SeqIO

with Entrez.efetch(db="nuccore", rettype="gb", retmode="full", id="NC_007384") as handle:
    seq_record = SeqIO.read(handle, "gb") 

print(seq_record)
```

which gives me a short version of gb file so the command:

```
seq_record.features
```

does not return features.

In comparison, there is no problem when I do the same thing with GenBank ID:

```
with Entrez.efetch(db="nuccore", rettype="gb", retmode="full", id="CP014768.1") as handle:
    seq_record = SeqIO.read(handle, "gb") 

print(seq_record)
```

After that I can extract every annotated feature from the list seq_record.features.

Is there a way to download full RefSeq records using Efetch?

Answer (score 3):

You need to either use `style="withparts"` or change `rettype` to `gbwithparts` to fetch all of the features. This [table](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25499/table/chapter4.T._valid_values_of__retmode_and/?report=objectonly) has some information.

```
>>> from Bio import Entrez
>>> from Bio import SeqIO
>>> Entrez.email = 'someone@email.com'
>>> with Entrez.efetch(db="nuccore", rettype="gb", retmode="full", id="NC_007384") as handle:
...     seq_record = SeqIO.read(handle, "gb") 
... 
>>> len(seq_record.features)
1
>>> with Entrez.efetch(db="nuccore", rettype="gbwithparts", retmode="full", id="NC_007384") as handle:
...     seq_record = SeqIO.read(handle, "gb") 
... 
>>> len(seq_record.features)
10616
>>> with Entrez.efetch(db="nuccore", rettype="gb", style="withparts", retmode="full", id="NC_007384") as handle:
...     seq_record = SeqIO.read(handle, "gb")
... 
>>> len(seq_record.features)
10616
```

Comment: This information is extremely useful to me, though I can't find options for the "style" keyword documented anywere either on the BioPythonn or efetch documentations, do you have a source for that?

Comment: Additionally: retmode='full' as this didn't appear to be an option for nuccore on the table you linked.